# Do we need to clear a timeout when using requestAnimationFrame polyfill?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

There is a requestAnimationFrame [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671) for older browsers which falls back to `setTimeout()`. I am wondering if we need to clear this timeout when using `window.requestAnimationFrame()`. Here is an example of a code snippet:

```
var timeout;

window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function() {
    if ( timeout ) {
        window.cancelAnimationFrame( timeout );
    }

    timeout = window.requestAnimationFrame( myFunction );
}, false );
```

Or should it be just like this (if yes, then could you please explain why?):

```
window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame( myFunction );
}, false );
```

Comment: it really depends on what you do in `myFunction`.

Comment: A proper polyfill will also polyfill `cancelAnimationFrame`, so no you don't need to change anything in your code

Comment: @bergi Do you have any links to a proper (and latest) polyfill source ?

Comment: The one you found looks fine, it does what I described.

Answer (score 0):

It should be used as native requestAnimationFrame. Just think this is the native implementation, and if you need to call cancelRequestAnimationFrame, then you need call it still.